# Why does this text-field send data properly but it is received as Null and Visual Studio raises exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-binding

I send data from view to action. Chrome browser shows that **Genre_Id is sent properly** as it you see the attached screenshot but when it is received by the action, Visual Studio raises exception and shows it as **Null / 0** as you see the attached screenshot. So why does this happen?

[image]

[image]

**this is Movie Model**

```
 public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Created on")]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Number in Stock")]
    public int NumberInStock { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Genre")]
    public int Genre_Id;

}
```

**this is the Form**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Save", "Movies"))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.Name, new { @class="form-control"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.DateAdded)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.DateAdded, new { @class="form-control"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.ReleaseDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.ReleaseDate, new { @class="form-control"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.NumberInStock)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.NumberInStock, new { @class="form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.Genre_Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.Genre_Id, new { @class="form-control"})
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Movie.Id)
<button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the icons, the Genre_Id member looks different. That's because it's a field, not a property.

MVC requires model members to be properties. Add `{ get; set; }` to its declaration.